# GWT import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBrowser Problem

Tags: java, gwt, interface

I am using GWT 2.1 but I am getting an error when importing this

import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBrowser;

it is giving the error

The import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBrowser conflicts with a type defined in the same file

I have tried in an emmpty project but getting the same error. 
Does somebody know about this??

Comment: If you`r creating class with the class name CellBrowser then it is in conflict with import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBrowser;

Comment: Thanks,, No, I think the problem is with the IDE, i need to fix this

Comment: Can you use other GWT widgets without compile error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a quick fix, try referring to com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBrowser using the fully qualified name rather than importing it.

Comment: +1 This error occurs (generally in Java, not only in GWT), when the type name in the file is the same as the imported type's (unqualified) name. (By the way, your fix is probably the only fix - aside from renaming the type.)